# Merge DF's on str ID and take averages

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I have a bunch of csvs in a folder in this format:

```
chunk   timecodes   chunk_completed chunk_id    diffs_avg   sd
0   [53]    [[45930]]   [45930] 53      
1   [53, 50]    [[45930], [46480]]  [46480] 53-50   550.0   
2   [53, 50, 63]    [[45930], [46480], [47980]] [47980] 53-50-63    1025.0  671.7514421272201
3   [53, 50, 63, 60]    [[45930], [46480], [47980], [49360]]    [49360] 53-50-63-60 1143.3333333333333  517.3329037798903
4   [53, 50, 63, 60, 73]    [[45930], [46480], [47980], [49360], [50040]]   [50040] 53-50-63-60-73  1027.5  481.75893003313035
5   [53, 50, 63, 60, 73, 70]    [[45930], [46480], [47980], [49360], [50040], [50310]]  [50310] 53-50-63-60-73-70   876.0   537.4290650867331
6   [50]    [[46480]]   [46480] 50      
7   [50, 63]    [[46480], [47980]]  [47980] 50-63   1500.0  
8   [50, 63, 60]    [[46480], [47980], [49360]] [49360] 50-63-60    1440.0  84.8528137423857
9   [50, 63, 60, 73]    [[46480], [47980], [49360], [50040]]    [50040] 50-63-60-73 1186.6666666666667  442.86943147313
```

I am read them in as DF's and make a list of the DF's:

```
csvs = []
list_of_files = [i for i in glob.glob('*.{}'.format('csv'))]
for file in list_of_files:
    f = pd.read_csv(file)
    csvs.append(f)
```

What I am trying to do is reduce them down to one dataframe with no repetitions of "chunk_id". Instead, I would like to merge on this ID.

I tried this:

```
from functools import reduce
red = reduce(pd.merge, csvs)
```

which just gives me a really wide dataframe with no entries.

I haven't attempted the averaging yet, but I would like to end up with a dataframe that has exactly the same columns as the example above, but where each row in all the dataframes with the same "chunk_id" is merged but their "diffs_avg", "timecodes", "chunk_completed" and "sd" columns averaged.

So, if I had read in the following dfs:

DF1

```
chunk   timecodes   chunk_completed chunk_id    diffs_avg   sd
[60 62]      [100, 200]        500       60-62       2         1
[58 53]      [800, 900]        1000       58-53       4         6
```

DF2

```
chunk   timecodes   chunk_completed chunk_id    diffs_avg   sd
[60 62]      [200, 400]        1000       60-62       4         2
[30 33]      [200, 700]        800       30-33       6         7
```

**RESULT:**

```
*[60 62]      [150, 300]        750       60-62       3         1.5*
[58 53]      [800, 900]        1000       58-53       4         6
[30 33]      [200, 700]        800       30-33       6         7
```

**Reproducible DF:**

```
{'chunk': {0: '[53]',
  1: '[53, 50]',
  2: '[53, 50, 63]',
  3: '[53, 50, 63, 60]',
  4: '[53, 50, 63, 60, 73]',
  5: '[53, 50, 63, 60, 73, 70]',
  6: '[50]',
  7: '[50, 63]',
  8: '[50, 63, 60]',
  9: '[50, 63, 60, 73]'},
 'chunk_completed': {0: '[45930]',
  1: '[46480]',
  2: '[47980]',
  3: '[49360]',
  4: '[50040]',
  5: '[50310]',
  6: '[46480]',
  7: '[47980]',
  8: '[49360]',
  9: '[50040]'},
 'chunk_id': {0: '53',
  1: '53-50',
  2: '53-50-63',
  3: '53-50-63-60',
  4: '53-50-63-60-73',
  5: '53-50-63-60-73-70',
  6: '50',
  7: '50-63',
  8: '50-63-60',
  9: '50-63-60-73'},
 'diffs_avg': {0: np.nan,
  1: 550.0,
  2: 1025.0,
  3: 1143.3333333333333,
  4: 1027.5,
  5: 876.0,
  6: np.nan,
  7: 1500.0,
  8: 1440.0,
  9: 1186.6666666666667},
 'sd': {0: np.nan,
  1: np.nan,
  2: 671.7514421272201,
  3: 517.3329037798903,
  4: 481.75893003313035,
  5: 537.4290650867331,
  6: np.nan,
  7: np.nan,
  8: 84.8528137423857,
  9: 442.86943147313},
 'timecodes': {0: '[[45930]]',
  1: '[[45930], [46480]]',
  2: '[[45930], [46480], [47980]]',
  3: '[[45930], [46480], [47980], [49360]]',
  4: '[[45930], [46480], [47980], [49360], [50040]]',
  5: '[[45930], [46480], [47980], [49360], [50040], [50310]]',
  6: '[[46480]]',
  7: '[[46480], [47980]]',
  8: '[[46480], [47980], [49360]]',
  9: '[[46480], [47980], [49360], [50040]]'}}
```

Comment: Which type is column timecodes? Are these lists or strings?

Comment: Please add the dataframe code, so that people working on this directly copy-paste it,

Comment: They are strings, but they should be a list of integers. That's a mistake which I'll have to sort.

Comment: Added reproducible DF.

Comment: This is not the appended df right? Because im not seeing any duplicate `chunk_id` so its not the same as your two small example dataframe. This changed your question to be honest.

Comment: The solution you wrote before seems to have worked. Thank you.

Comment: Then I will post it as answer again @SebSilas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing your `timecodes` column and which type it has, you can average the rest over `chunk_id` by using [`pandas.DataFrame.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and `.agg`

```
# First of all you should concat your csv's into one big dataframe:
df3 = pd.concat(csvs, axis=0, ignore_index=True)
```

```
# First we concat df1 & df2 which is the appending of the CSV's
# Note this is a simulation of your csv's
df3 = pd.concat([df1,df2], ignore_index=True)

print(df3)
     chunk   timecodes  chunk_completed chunk_id  diffs_avg  sd
0  [60 62]  [100, 200]              500    60-62          2   1
1  [58 53]  [800, 900]             1000    58-53          4   6
2  [60 62]  [200, 400]             1000    60-62          4   2
3  [30 33]  [200, 700]              800    30-33          6   7
```

Now we can aggregate with groupby

```
df_grouped = df3.groupby('chunk_id').agg({'chunk_completed':'mean',
                                          'diffs_avg':'mean',
                                          'sd':'mean'}).reset_index()

print(df_grouped)
  chunk_id  chunk_completed  diffs_avg   sd
0    30-33              800          6  7.0
1    58-53             1000          4  6.0
2    60-62              750          3  1.5
```

Comment: This isn't a complete solution since a main issue is retrieving multiple files which from a directory which become many dataframes. How could this work with concat?

Comment: Its to simulate your appending of CSV's which I understood was already done by you and not your problem. I cannot "append" your csv's, I dont have them. Its just to show I `append` the two dataframes. @SebSilas

Comment: Additionally, how might we get an average for each item in the list in the timecodes column? Assuming it is a list of integers.

Comment: I can add additional answer to show that in your two small example dataframes. But your reproducible datafame is more complex since the amount of values in each timecodes row are different.

Comment: How do I keep other columns in here without applying a function to them?